# How to replicate POST login with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, swift, post, nsurlsession

I'm trying to write a iOS app to be my personal front-end to my city library's website.  In effect, I want my app to invisibly visit the library's webpage, enter my username and password, and then send HTTP requests to invisibly browse through the library's web interface to get my list of checked-out items, renew items near their due dates, etc.

The first step is to be able to send in my username and password.  I've stripped down the library's login page to the following:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="http://brown.ent.sirsi.net/client/en_US/home/search/patronlogin.loginpageform/TRAINING" method="post">
        <input name="t:ac" type="hidden" value="http:$002f$002fbrown.ent.sirsi.net"></input>
        <input name="t:formdata" type="hidden" value="gFJQUIXDSUXVXoGv49wm3q8cIUQ=:H4sIAAAAAAAAAFvzloG1XJ5Btjg1sSg5Qz8gsaQoP88nPz0zzyorvrQ4tSgvMTe1uIjBNL8oXS+xIDE5I1WvJLEgtbikqNJULzm/KDUnM0kvKbE4Vc8xCSiYmFzilpmak6ISnFpSWqAaepj7oejxP0wMjD4M3Mn5eUDTc/yAJpYwCPlkJZYl6uck5qXrB5cUZealW1cUlDBwIWwlxlmOpDoroCg/ObW4OLg0KTezuDgzP+/wuhSTtG/zzjExMFQU4LSyILG4uDy/KKW4kKGOgQHsTJgQQT0gLazl0gySWFRlZKakpOYBPeKA1yPJ+bkF+XmpeSXFeh5gHZj+iGpXEK6Q3sGGEdQg6xlBQcsGsQyHS4pBJpWQ4hKw3SWYLpkZ/Ely65YWZyYGJh8GjuScTKBqT3AogFyWmpOaCxRAcRkHxPJ4AyQmABiJtLaZAgAA"></input>
        Library Card #: <input name="j_username" value = "29878001234567" type="text"></input><br/>
        PIN: <input name="j_password" value="1234" type="text"></input><br/>
        <input name="hidden" value="SYMWS" type="hidden"></input>
        <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open this HTML file from my hard drive, enter my real library card number and PIN, and submit the form, I successfully log into the library's system.  When I click on "submit" with just the dummy numbers in the code above, I receive the "login failed" screen just as I should.

I've tried to imitate this in my Swift code as follows:

```
func loginToLibrary() {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://brown.ent.sirsi.net/client/en_US/home/search/patronlogin.loginpageform/TRAINING")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var postString = "t:ac=http:$002f$002fbrown.ent.sirsi.net"
    postString += "&t:formdata=gFJQUIXDSUXVXoGv49wm3q8cIUQ=:H4sIAAAAAAAAAFvzloG1XJ5Btjg1sSg5Qz8gsaQoP88nPz0zzyorvrQ4tSgvMTe1uIjBNL8oXS+xIDE5I1WvJLEgtbikqNJULzm/KDUnM0kvKbE4Vc8xCSiYmFzilpmak6ISnFpSWqAaepj7oejxP0wMjD4M3Mn5eUDTc/yAJpYwCPlkJZYl6uck5qXrB5cUZealW1cUlDBwIWwlxlmOpDoroCg/ObW4OLg0KTezuDgzP+/wuhSTtG/zzjExMFQU4LSyILG4uDy/KKW4kKGOgQHsTJgQQT0gLazl0gySWFRlZKakpOYBPeKA1yPJ+bkF+XmpeSXFeh5gHZj+iGpXEK6Q3sGGEdQg6xlBQcsGsQyHS4pBJpWQ4hKw3SWYLpkZ/Ely65YWZyYGJh8GjuScTKBqT3AogFyWmpOaCxRAcRkHxPJ4AyQmABiJtLaZAgAA"
    postString += "&j_username=29878001234567"
    postString += "&j_password=1234"
    postString += "&hidden=SYMWS"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("response to login attempt = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

When I run the Swift code, however, the following is printed to the console:

```
response to login attempt = Optional(<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/client/assets/4.5.03/ctx/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.mircrosoft.icon" id="favicon"/><title>Unexpected Error</title><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/client/assets/4.5.03/core/default.css"/><meta content="Apache Tapestry Framework (version 5.3.7)" name="generator"/></head><body><div id="exception"><h1>Unexpected Error</h1><div class="pageheading">The system encountered an error while processing the following request:</div><div class="url">/en_US/home/search/patronlogin.loginpageform/TRAINING</div><h2>Error Summary</h2><div class="cause">java.io.IOException: Client data associated with the current request appears to have been tampered with (the HMAC signature does not match).</div><div class="timestamp">Wed May 25 22:51:42 CDT 2016</div></div></body></html>)
```

Interpreting that in a browser, it is:

---

Unexpected Error

## Unexpected Error

The system encountered an error while processing the following request:/en_US/home/search/patronlogin.loginpageform/TRAINING

### Error Summary

java.io.IOException: Client data associated with the current request appears to have been tampered with (the HMAC signature does not match).Wed May 25 22:51:42 CDT 2016)

---

Can anyone please help me figure out how the POST request sent by my Swift code differs from the POST request my browser sends from the stripped-down webpage above?

For what it's worth, I can obtain the same error (HMAC signature not matching) in the browser from my stripped-down webpage if I change the value of the `t:formdata` input.  I've tried percent-encoding the `=` (about 30 characters into the `t:formdata` value) as `%3D`, and even the `/`'s as `%2F`, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

### The site you're trying to post to is using HMAC to authenticate.

**Short Answer:** You can't accomplish what you're trying. You need to do some research to work around HMAC.

**Long Answer:**
A HMAC(Hash-based Message Authentication Code) is the product of a hash function applied to the body of a message along with a secret key. So rather than sending the username and password with a Web service request, you send some identifier for the private key and an HMAC. When the server receives the request, it looks up the user’s private key and uses it to create an HMAC for the incoming request. If the HMAC submitted with the request matches the one calculated by the server, then the request is authenticated.

There are two big advantages. The first is that the HMAC allows you to verify the password (or private key) without requiring the user to embed it in the request, and the second is that the HMAC also verifies the basic integrity of the request. If an attacker manipulated the request in any way in transit, the signatures would not match and the request would not be authenticated. This is a huge win, especially if the Web service requests are not being made over a secure HTTP connection.

Look into this [link](http://rc3.org/2011/12/02/using-hmac-to-authenticate-web-service-requests/) for more information on HMAC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your link.  I've done some reading at that link and others.  I think I understand the theory of the more secure login, but what I still don't quite get is how my browser knows to do anything other than send the username and password in cleartext as a HTTP POST request.  What part of the stripped-down HTML file I included above tells my browser to compute an HMAC and send that?  Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Your browser does not compute anything. The server generates the key using a hash function. The server also generates a a secret key which is not shared with the user. When the browser sends a request, the server checks the headers with the secret key it has. If the data is tampered with, the server drops the request. You are clearly modifying the information in the headers in you `loginToLibrary()` method. You need to figure out a way to append the user name and password without tampering the headers. This is all the help I can give and you need to pick it up from here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

URL encode is missing for the data you post to symphony, I have got the same issue you encountered. That is the reason why symphony got a wrong t:formdata

Comment: please show the code line that is problematic or post the right code